# Does using the phrase "operational state" imply that the referenced "thing" is inanimate?

Tags: meaning, phrases, word-usage

Can it also be used while referring to animate "things"?

*OED* has the following definition which might indicate that we can use *operational* for people but there are only metaphoric examples related to people.

> In a condition of readiness to perform some intended (originally military) function; able and ready to function. Also in weakened sense: working, in use.

However, *[dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/operational)* has the following definition and example:

> on active service or combat duty:
>
> *All units of the command are operational.*

Does it mean we can only use *operational* for people in military context? How about *operational state*?

Comment: Hi Kaan! I tried to make your question a better one by editing it. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the phrase “operational state” does not imply a referenced item is inanimate.  One can find many instances of phrases like “he is operational” or  “she is operational” via [google](https://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&q=%22she+is+operational%22&oq=%22she+is+operational%22&gs_l=hp.3..0i8i7i30.31913.31913.1.32597.1.1.0.0.0.0.329.329.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.19.psy-ab.EWvK6wSKfr4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.cGE&fp=7a715259d205aff3&biw=1052&bih=595).

The “he is operational” phrase typically is applied to people such as special-services [operatives](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/operative#Noun) (*ie*, spies, secret agents, detectives).  One can ask, *eg*,  “What is Tom's operational state?” without  implying Tom is inanimate.

The “she is operational” phrase typically is applied to ships, boats, locomotives, etc, making the situation less clear; but it need not imply the subject is inanimate.  [For example](http://www.wyomingk9sar.org/profile/tammy_halstead.htm), in

> She is also operational in Cadaver with her third dog, Palmer

*she* refers to a live person.

Comment: Having looked up your link, I understand the quoted phrase but "operational in Cadaver" does sound particularly strange! (The sentence from which you quote also seems strange as I would have expected the noun 'detection' or similar on the end.)